# python round(x[, n]) replacing x with a specified variable

Tags: variables, python-2.7, rounding

basically what I want to know is how to make this work:

```
print "He weighs %f kilograms" % round(Metricmy_weight, 2)
```

It prints 
    He weighs 100.000000 kilograms

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If what you want to print is `100.00`, specify the precision with (`%.2f`):

```
>>> print 'He weighs %.2f kilograms' % 100
He weighs 100.00 kilograms
```